# Restore lines deleted in the last commit but keep added lines. Combine files line-wise unified

Tags: bash, git

I made some changes in several files by editing lines (as usual) and made a commit.
Then assumptions changed and I figured out I need to actually use both the deleted lines AND added lines nicely together. How to restore the deleted lines (exactly as `git show` displays in red) but keep also the added (green) lines without manual copy-pasting from the previous revision?

Preferable way would be to trigger a "merge-like" conflict resolution between the previous and the current commit. I would then clean markers keeping everything else (from both sources). Of course I can't do it since commits are on a merged path.

Another way would be extracting both versions of a given file and combine them "line-wise" (as a unified diff format) into a single file with some Bash text-processing tool.

I may have overlooked something trivial. What is the easiest work-flow to aggregate up those all diff-affected lines (either by conflict resolution or some other trick)?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways that I would go about doing this.  You can do a `git revert <sha of deleted commit>`.  This will create a new commit that is the inverse of the commit.

Or you can `git checkout <sha of deleted commit>~ -- <files changed>` and the manually make a new commit adding the lines using `git add -p` to stage.

Depending on where in the file your lines were added, you may end up with a conflict but this should be relatively minor to handle.

Comment: `git revert` (to get that "inversion"), `cherry-pick` it to a parallel branch and merge both to obtain that aggregate. Am I reasoning well?

Comment: You should be able to do this all on a single branch, you can skip the cherry-pick.  But that should also work.

Comment: I couldn't get that to give desired effect. Would you mind elaborating how to utilize that reverted "mirror" to accumulate both deleted lines (existing only in the previous revision) and added lines (introduced in the revision checked out now) into the same file?